# recursive query for single table

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

i am try to get number of records which are directly/indirectly link to a to_id. From table here, i wants to count number of records here link to id say(1). So from this the number of id related to 1 are (2,3,6,9,11,17) 6.

```
from_id|to_id 
 2     |1
 3     |2
 4     |7
 6     |2
 9     |3
 10    |7
 11    |3
 17    |11
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+recursive+query